# 2 mysql tables, a single row links to multiple entries in another table. how can I only get the single row once rather than for every other entry

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Sorry the title may sound confusing and I have done it before but 14 hours in to a coding session I am stuck and my brain is ready to explode.

I have a table with a id, name and description and a table which has multiple entries linked to the first table id.

I want to return an array which has the first tables description and name once then all the entries it links to next in the array.

The below code returns an array I can loop through but the description and name for the single row is in every other entry.

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare('
            SELECT 
                cl.name,
                cl.description,
                cf.*
             FROM 
                contentList as cl
             LEFT JOIN
                contentFiles as cf
             ON
                cl.contentid = cf.contentid

              WHERE cl.contentid = :contentid
        ');
        $stmt->bindValue(':contentid', $contentid);
        $stmt->execute();

        $content = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

This returns this which will hopefully explain what I do not want it to do

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => First List yea
        [0] => First List yea
        [description] => This is my first document
        [1] => This is my first document
        [fileid] => 28
        [2] => 28
        [fileName] => 22_project_plan.pdf
        [3] => 22_project_plan.pdf
        [fileSize] => 1694506
        [4] => 1694506
        [fileType] => applicatio
        [5] => applicatio
        [deleted] => 1
        [6] => 1
        [contentid] => 8
        [7] => 8
        [userid] => 22
        [8] => 22
        [fileDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [9] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => First List yea
        [0] => First List yea
        [description] => This is my first document
        [1] => This is my first document
        [fileid] => 29
        [2] => 29
        [fileName] => 22_about.jpg
        [3] => 22_about.jpg
        [fileSize] => 213162
        [4] => 213162
        [fileType] => image/jpeg
        [5] => image/jpeg
        [deleted] => 1
        [6] => 1
        [contentid] => 8
        [7] => 8
        [userid] => 22
        [8] => 22
        [fileDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [9] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => First List yea
        [0] => First List yea
        [description] => This is my first document
        [1] => This is my first document
        [fileid] => 30
        [2] => 30
        [fileName] => 22_arrow.png
        [3] => 22_arrow.png
        [fileSize] => 18059
        [4] => 18059
        [fileType] => image/png
        [5] => image/png
        [deleted] => 1
        [6] => 1
        [contentid] => 8
        [7] => 8
        [userid] => 22
        [8] => 22
        [fileDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [9] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )
```

Sorry for the poor explanation, thank you in advance.

Sorry output I want it to be is similar to

```
        [name] => First List yea
        [0] => First List yea
        [description] => This is my first document

    [0] => Array
    (
        [fileid] => 28
        [2] => 28
        [fileName] => 22_project_plan.pdf
        [3] => 22_project_plan.pdf
        [fileSize] => 1694506
        [4] => 1694506
        [fileType] => applicatio
        [5] => applicatio
        [deleted] => 1
        [6] => 1
        [contentid] => 8
        [7] => 8
        [userid] => 22
        [8] => 22
        [fileDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [9] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [fileid] => 29
        [2] => 29
        [fileName] => 22_about.jpg
        [3] => 22_about.jpg
        [fileSize] => 213162
        [4] => 213162
        [fileType] => image/jpeg
        [5] => image/jpeg
        [deleted] => 1
        [6] => 1
        [contentid] => 8
        [7] => 8
        [userid] => 22
        [8] => 22
        [fileDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [9] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => This is my first document
        [fileid] => 30
        [2] => 30
        [fileName] => 22_arrow.png
        [3] => 22_arrow.png
        [fileSize] => 18059
        [4] => 18059
        [fileType] => image/png
        [5] => image/png
        [deleted] => 1
        [6] => 1
        [contentid] => 8
        [7] => 8
        [userid] => 22
        [8] => 22
        [fileDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [9] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )
```

IE multi dimensional array, was thinking I could have done it with a JOIN rather than 2 queries

Comment: add what you would like the output to be; but i suspect the answer is going to be 'do it in the application, not the database'

Comment: updated, hopefully makes sense, assuming a multi dimensional array but thought I could get the data with one query

Comment: You do get the data with each query, you just need to reorganize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `$content = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
try:

```
$content = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  if(!isset($content[$row['name']])) {
    $content[$row['name']] = array ('description' => $row['description'], data => array());
  }
  $content[$row['name']]['data'][] = $row;
}
```

that should give you an output closer to what you would like. you can't get the data organised like this straight out of the database unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thought I had done it in a mysql statement before but I guess not, thats pretty much perfect.

Comment: the database can only return rows, and all rows have the same fields, so yeah, any further manipulation is application level. glad it helped.